# How to use mongoose object in another node file?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to node.js . I am trying to create one connection in server.js and use it in addAcction.js but got error while running "Software is not
    a constructor", Please help me this?

```
   //Server .js
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/MSDN');
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));
    db.once('open', function callback() {
      console.log("Connection with database succeeded.");
    });
    module.exports = db;
    var SoftwareSchema   = new mongoose.Schema({
          SoftwareID: Number,
          SoftwareName: String,
        });
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Software', SoftwareSchema);

   //addAction.js

    var Software = require('./Server').Software;
    var Software1 = new Software({
    SoftwareID   : 1,
    SoftwareName : "MNG123",  
    });
    Software1.save(function(err){
       if ( err ) throw err;
       console.log("Software Saved Successfully");
   });
```

Comment: Did you try to set the variables outside? Like s1 = new Software(); s1.softwareId = 1; s1.softwareName = "MNG123"; s1.save(...)

Comment: @israel.zinc tried facing same error :(

Comment: ah, try to remove the .software after your require.